# Initialize a headless RaspberryPi connected by Wifi, 100% from Windows

Tags: raspbian, wifi, boot, headless

This works to initialize a headless RaspberryPi connected by Wifi (no screen/keyboard never needed attached to RPi):

1. Get a Raspbian Stretch Lite from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ and write it to the micro SD card with Win32diskimager or Etcher
2. Add an empty `ssh` file in the boot partition
3. Boot on Linux (or boot a Linux VM on Windows), or use [Linux File Systems for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/) **in order to edit `/etc/network/intefaces`** and add:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   allow-hotplug wlan0
   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-ssid "MyRouter"
   wpa-psk "92dc84ee7e7032be9142828023912e77"

   allow-hotplug eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
   ```

This works, I've done it many times in the past years.

Problem: **for a Windows user, step #3 is not very convenient.** An alternative would be to initially connect via ethernet cable, SSH with putty, and edit `/etc/network/intefaces` with `nano`, but it's not very handy too, because it requires to connect the RPi to the router with a cable.

**Question: which method would allow to initialize a headless Raspberry Pi, including the Wifi ssid/password setting, 100% from Windows?**

I see a few options:

- A) Would there be a way, on a fresh Stretch Lite install, **only by modifying files in the `boot` partition (accessible from Windows)**, to configure Raspbian to use a file `intefaces` in the boot partition instead of the usual  `/etc/network/interfaces` ?
- B) Would there be a way to put a script `copyinterfaces.sh` in the `boot` partition:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  sudo cp /boot/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces
  ```

  that would be launched on the first boot of the RPi? Then we could put both the `intefaces` file (written in the boot partition - easy from Windows) and the `copyinterfaces.sh` file in the boot partition, and during the first boot, the boot partition's `interfaces` file would be copied to `/etc/network/interfaces`
- C) another idea?

Once again, the goal is: **to be able to set up a headless RPi connected by wifi, without using a keyboard/screen/ethernet cable ever, 100% from Windows, so that we can SSH with putty and never have to boot Linux (some users don't have any Linux installation), and never have to use an ethernet cable.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See **Headless Raspbian WiFi Setup** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

> Specifically Raspbian checks the contents of the boot directory for a file called wpa_supplicant.conf, and will copy the file into /etc/wpa_supplicant, replacing any existing wpa_supplicant.conf file that may be there. The file in the boot directory is then removed. This can be used to enable headless setup.

NOTE the etc/network/intefaces you listed is obsolete and is not needed. Even in 2015 it would have been poor practice but it has been replaced by `dhcpcd` which is far more robust.

Comment: Yes. (I don't use Windows, but it certainly works - you may need to use LF line endings rather than CR/LF which can be done with Notepad)

Comment: See the link for sample files.

Comment: @Basj If you have another question, ask another question properly.  And no, don't replace those paths. `wpa_supplicant` != `wpa_supplicant.conf`.  The paths are part of the configuration, they don't refer to the configuration file itself (which would be a bit non-sensical).  Also, that file is moved before it is used (*"Raspbian checks the contents of the boot directory for a file called wpa_supplicant.conf, and **will copy the file** into /etc/wpa_supplicant"*).

Answer (score 2):

Additional information to the accepted answer:

1. Write the Raspbian Stretch Lite image to the SD card
2. Create a `ssh` empty file in the boot partition
3. Create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file in the boot partition containing:

   ```
   ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
   update_config=1
   country=FR
   network={
     ssid="MyRouter"
     psk="the_password"
   }
   ```
4. Boot the RPi and connect it via SSH (for example with putty.exe from Windows). It works, 100% from Windows!

Important note: I've tried with only a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file containing only:

```
network={
  ssid="MyRouter"
  psk="the_password"
}
```

but it did not work; the other lines (`update_config`...) seem mandatory.

Comment: More info about the wpa_supplicant.conf options (such as update_config): https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf